# Why do these base64 encoding outputs differ, given the same input string?

Tags: javascript, groovy, go, base64, gnu

When getting a bas64 encoded string from the same input string I find that JavaScript, Groovy, and Go have the same result, but GNU base64 is slightly different.  Why is that?

**JavaScript (nodejs v0.10.33):**

```
new Buffer('Laurence Tureaud is Mr. T').toString('base64');
TGF1cmVuY2UgVHVyZWF1ZCBpcyBNci4gVA==
```

**Groovy (2.3.7 on Java 8):**

```
'Laurence Tureaud is Mr. T'.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
TGF1cmVuY2UgVHVyZWF1ZCBpcyBNci4gVA==
```

**Go (1.4):**

```
b64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte("Laurence Tureaud is Mr. T"))
TGF1cmVuY2UgVHVyZWF1ZCBpcyBNci4gVA==
```

**GNU base64 (GNU coreutils 8.12.197-032bb with UTF-8 term charset):**

```
echo 'Laurence Tureaud is Mr. T' | base64
TGF1cmVuY2UgVHVyZWF1ZCBpcyBNci4gVAo=
```

Comment: Are they using the same encoding?

Comment: If you decode the results you'll see that the GNU base64 has a new line character at the end. (You get 'Laurence Tureaud is Mr. T\n' where \n is a new line.

Comment: try `echo -n 'Laurence Tureaud is Mr. T' | base64`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `echo 'Laurence Tureaud is Mr. T'`

Echo adds a newline after the string.

Try the following to remove the newline:

`echo -n 'Laurence Tureaud is Mr. T' | base64`

And you get `TGF1cmVuY2UgVHVyZWF1ZCBpcyBNci4gVA==`

Comment: Ah, yes, that was it indeed.  The following matches:
printf 'Laurence Tureaud is Mr. T' | base64

Comment: @user605331 If this worked for you, please mark this as the correct solution. Thanks! :)

Comment: SO won't allow until 5 minutes has passed.  I tried.

Comment: @user605331 Sorry, didn't mean to rush you. Just wanted to put a little reminder. I added a little more to this answer for future reference!

Answer (score 4):

All output is the same.

The only difference is that bash appends a newline (`\n`) to the end when using `echo`. Therefore the is an additional character appended to the output (the character `=` is only a padding in base64).